# How to not display dropt list in fine uploader?

Tags: fine-uploader

I need help with this.

I am using fineUploader and I would like to not display the upload list.

My current template :

```
<div>
<script type="text/template" id="qq-template-manual-trigger">
    <div class="qq-uploader-selector baz-uploader" qq-drop-area-text="{{dropZoneText}}">
        <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container">
            <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
            <span class="qq-upload-drop-area-text-selector"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
                <div>{{::selectFilesButton}}</div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
            <span>{{::processing}}</span>
            <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
            <li>
                <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector">
                    <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner baz-upload-spinner"></span>
                <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" qq-max-size="100" width="30" qq-server-scale>
                <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel">Annuler</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry">Réessayer</button>
                <span role="status" class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>
<div id="baz-fine-uploader"></div>
```

I have tried to remove the ul tag "qq-upload-list-selector" directly but the drop zone is no longer display.

Comment: If you don't want to display the upload list, why are you using Fine Uploader UI at all?

Comment: CSS to the rescue. Just use display:none or something.

Comment: @AlboBest thank you !

Comment: @RayNicholus in certains cases, I need to not display the upload list